# replacement of "how" with "the way"

Tags: wh-questions

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/vision-of-how.3581472/):
**(1)** *He had a clear vision **of how** he hoped the company would develop*. — correct
**(2)** *He had a clear vision **how** he hoped the company would develop*. — correct

As far as I know, if a sentence is not interrogative and not exclamative — i.e. when "how" doesn't stand at the beginning of a sentence and when a how-clause is a part of a complex sentence — we can always replace "how" with "the way". So I did it in (1) & (2):
**(3)** *He had a clear vision **of the way** he hoped the company would develop*.
**(4)** *He had a clear vision **the way** he hoped the company would develop*.
**(5)** *He had a clear vision **in the way** he hoped the company would develop*.

Could you tell me please which of them are correct and which are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker, who never learned English by rule, I think number 3 is perfect. Numbers 4 and 5, are neither grammatical nor idiomatic, in my view.

The word *vision* does require a preposition of some kind - "of" is clearly correct, another might be "about". One could say:

"He had a clear vision **about the way** he hoped the company would develop."

I do not consider number 2 of your examples with ***how*** to be correct. You need an "of" or an "about" in front of "how".

In these sentences you could also substitute a suitable "---ing" verb for the preposition e.g

"He had a clear vision ***involving the way/how*** he hoped the company would develop". Other possibilities might be: ***depicting/detailing/regarding***. Or you could say "He had a clear vision ***as regards the way/how*** the company would develop."